# gradlew publish is giving error not able to create copy on my repo

Tags: java, gradle, devops, nexus

### I am new with Nexus trying to run gradlew publish , but is giving error as mention below :

```
    C:\>gradlew publish
> Task :publishMavenPublicationToNexusRepository FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToNexusRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'nexus'
   > Invalid publication 'maven': artifact file does not exist:
```

I am trying to follow some Bootcamp training and this is the code I got :

---

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'

    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'nexus'
            url "http://139.59.150.201:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/"
            credentials {
                username project.repoUser
                password project.repoPassword
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this looks incomplete to me. if this is all you have than the publish command should not work (unless it's part of the spring boot plugin nowadays maybe).

I believe the syntax is also incorrect and that the repositories block should not be in the plugins closure.
Could you post the full settings.gradle and build.gradle files?

Answer (score 0):

```
 allowInsecureProtocol = true
```

add this and then it will work perfect.